# Can I make a unique compound index in MongoDB that enforces uniqueness on key permutation?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection that records correlation values between brands (nevermind how such a correlation would be generated or interpreted.)  Then the fields in this collection would include: 'brand1', 'brand2', and 'correlation'.

For the sake of an example, let's say that brands can take on string values such as "google", "microsoft", etc., so that each document records the correlation between various brand names.

I would want to create a unique index on the 'brand1' and 'brand2' fields so that each document records the correlation between a pair of brands only once in the collection. In order to do this, the ordering of the key in the index must be taken into account when determining uniqueness in the collection. A key of ['google', 'microsoft'] should be considered the same as a key of ['microsoft', 'google'], so that if a document already exists with the former key, an insertion of a document with the latter key would be prohibited.

Is this kind of index possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enforce that kind of constraint on a MongoDB collection.

What you can do, however, is enforce a constraint *in your software* that the two components of this index are always stored in sorted order. (For instance, always store `["a","b"]`, not `["b","a"]`.) This makes it so that there's only one "canonical" version of any pair in the collection.